# Newtonsoft Json helper class

Tags: c#, json

I've written the following helper class to help serializing objects to and from Json.

I would appreciate some feed back on the style of the class.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Helpers
{
    public static class Json
    {
        public static void SaveContractToJSON<T>(T contract, string filePath)
        {
            using (var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                SerializeToStream(contract, fs);
            }
        }

        public static void SaveContractToJSON<T>(T contract, MemoryStream stream)
        {
            SerializeToStream(contract, stream);
        }

        private static void SerializeToStream<T>(T contract, Stream stream)
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
            using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, contract);
            }
        }

        public static T LoadContractFromJSON<T>(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    return DeserializeFromStream<T>(fileStream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }

        public static T LoadContractFromJSON<T>(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            try
            {
                return DeserializeFromStream<T>(stream);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }

        private static T DeserializeFromStream<T>(Stream stream)
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class name is `Json` yet your methods contain this acronym in all-uppercase: `JSON`. The naming conventions say: ["**Do capitalize only the first character of acronyms with three or more characters**, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229043.aspx)

---

`fs` isn't a clear variable name. Same for `sw` (why not use `streamWriter`?) and `sr` (`streamReader`). I'd even include `writer`.

---

Considering that you don't use `var serializer = new JsonSerializer();` until later, why not delay this call until you need it?

---

I'm bothered by `catch (Exception)`. Are you certain you don't want to know that something went wrong, and what exactly went wrong?